# python matplotlib text colour does not set when using bbox

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I use the following code, the text colour does not get set. (Text colour comes out as black)

```
textBbox=dict(facecolor='w', edgecolor='None',alpha=0.9)

ax.text(0.5, 0.5 ,text,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    verticalalignment='top',
    bbox=textBbox,
    rotation="horizontal",
    size='x-small',
    weight='light',
    color="red",
    alpha=0.50,
    transform=trans)
```

if I remove the line

```
bbox=textBox,
```

then it will work correctly.

How can I use bbox and set the text colour?

Comment: what are you using as `trans` and what version of `matplatlib` are you using?  I can not reproduce this.